# how do i convert my html document into a website?

Tags: html, google-chrome, web

I have learned HTML CSS js but the problem is that when I code, I code over an HTML document and i can't find my website on google BCS it's an HTML document, therefore, I want help from you to make my own website link like https::/loremimpsum.com (.org .tb, etc.) problem

Comment: If you are building a "plain" website from HTML and CSS... you have tons of options. If you want your own domain, look into buying a domain with hosting... if you still want to experiment you might find a service like glitch.com to be helpful to design something online for free until you're ready to buy hosting.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Answer (score 1):

The "website link" is called a **domain** and you cannot make one. You can search for your desired domain address on many hosting sites and see if it's taken or not. If it's available, you will need to pay for it to be registered. Domains have to be **renewed annually** in most cases.

Before you can do anything with your domain though, you need to have **a server running which hosts your web services** (such as a webiste). Typically, this means a separate device (physical or virtual) which has a static public IP address. For experimenting purposes, you can set this up on your personal computer, but this is not advised for long-term hosting for multiple reasons.

There are **many types of web server softwares** and the right choice comes down to your personal project and needs. Most well known solutions are: Apache, IIS, Node.js...

When you have a server, you must **configure your DNS settings** (this happens on the website of your domain host) to point at the server's IP address. After this gets registered, your server can be reached over the internet, through your domain address.

Hosting a simple website can be as simple as dragging your site files (your `.html`, `.css`, `.js` files along with necessary assets) to a specific folder on the server - default generated might be: `<path>/www/` or `<path>/public_html/`. When developing simple `.html`, `.css`, `.js` files, there is absolutely **no conversion or compilation process**. The website is directly displayed from them.

<sup>If you use something like Angular however, then you'll want to `build` your project and move the generated package instead (which is just a collection of the previously mentioned files).</sup>

Web browsers try to access port 80 (for HTTP) or 443 (for HTTPS) to display your website. You want your website service to listen to these ports, but this might be already part of your default config files for the web server software. You might need to do additional firewall configuration to allow traffic to reach your services.

---

You can rent a web server which is ready to host your content for you. Of course this involves a monthly fee if you want to have anything that's useful.

Answer (score -1):

Websites are not converted or complied.
The html document is on your computer but a website is seen and stored on a server.
so the html file will be present in the server.
Now you can get a server but it will not be hosted meaning no other computer would be connected to it.
Also server and website hosting costs much but there are some free website hosters like 000webhost.com
You can literally get your own url.

Comment: Please make punctuation better and use bold and code frames where needed. The answer looking like a paragraph of random info is less likely to be helpful and read, hence unlikely to be accepted.

Comment: You linked to your own product or website in your post. There are some [guidelines in place](/help/promotion) for doing so. In particular, I'd like to call your attention to this line: "Post good, relevant answers, and if some (**but not all**) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay." To continue contributing to this site, you must also ask and answer questions that do not involve self-promotion.  I also question whether the link to your website is even necessary for this answer.